# What is the most common way of administering loop diuretics and what is their time course of action?

Tags: pharmacology, pharmacokinetics

I am reviewing some material on loop diuretics, and I am curious to know how these drugs are administered. Also, I am interested in knowing their time course of action once they are administered into the body.

Answer (score 1):

I know that furosemide (there are [more types of loop diuretics](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLoop_diuretic&ei=-fFjVMO7GMXvmAWWrILIDw&usg=AFQjCNGa7YEm02czkwGn6fnwmNsszHCmdA&sig2=7AlzGm-s7YhQOjetoXnYVQ)) can be given intravenously (but can be orally given as well ([furosemide info sheet](http://www.drugs.com/ppa/furosemide.html))). Effects of i.v. furosemide are pretty much immediate as it is carried quickly to the kidneys via the blood. After i.v. administration the effects wear off in about half an hour. t<sub>1/2</sub> is about 2 hours, but likely depending on route of administration.